# How to get the value of OK and CANCEL from alertbox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to generate an alert box on button click. I have written like this

```
protected void btn_submit_click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
  btn_submit.OnClientClick = @"return confirm('Student has not completed all the steps? Are you sure you want to submit the details?');";
                    bool type = false;   
   if(type==true)
 {
    //If clicks OK button
  }
 else
{//If clicks CANCEL button
}
}
```

Alert box comes correctly. But how could I get the values from code behind?please help.

Comment: if(type-=true) oops here is mistake ,correct it if(type==true)

Comment: why dont you use `ClientScriptManager`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When confirm returns false, then there is no postback since the click event in the javascript is cancelled. If you want to have the postback after clicking cancel you need to change your code a little:

serverside:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     btn_submit.Click += btn_submit_click;
     btn_submit.OnClientClick = @"return getConfirmationValue();";
}

protected void btn_submit_click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{

                    bool type = false;   
   if(hfWasConfirmed.Value == "true")
 {
    //If clicks OK button
  }
 else
{//If clicks CANCEL button
}
}
```

on the client:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="hfWasConfirmed" />
<asp:Panel runat="server">
<script>
function getConfirmationValue(){
   if( confirm('Student has not completed all the steps? Are you sure you want to submit the details?')){
       $('#<%=hfWasConfirmed.ClientID%>').val('true')
   }
   else{
      $('#<%=hfWasConfirmed.ClientID%>').val('false')
   }
   return true;
}
</script>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: I think hfWasConfirmed.Value will store previous result, not the last. Isn't it?

Comment: @DraggonZ I think that javascript function will be evaluated before sending the form, therefore the new value of the hfWasConfirmed Control should be avalaible on the serverside

Comment: hfWasConfirmed.Value is not getting.(.Value is not there)

Comment: Probably OnClientClick should be in aspx. When user clicks buttons first time js will not call, because button doesn't have onClientClick event.

Comment: shows an error Error Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'bool'

Comment: I forgot to put the ClientID of the control, check my edited answer

Comment: @ARATHY hfWasConfirmed.Value == "true" - true should be a string

Comment: <asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="hfWasConfirmed" /> what is the role of this?? Need to change anything on web.config file?? show such an error

Comment: @ARATHY hfWasConfirmed is a web control that will transfer user choice to the serverside code. If the user choses ok then the value of the hidden field will be "true", and when opposite it will be equal to "false". By checking the value you will know in server side code what the user clicked when confirmation window pop up .

Comment: shows .. -Control 'hfWasConfirmed' of type 'HiddenField' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Comment: alert box is not coming

Comment: hfWasConfirmed.Value IS GETTING NULL ..PLEASE HELP @Adam Moszczyński

Comment: @ARATHY you can put the code marked as "on the client" in my answer below your "btn_submit" control and it should work

Comment: @ARATHY According to DraggonZ comment you should put yours OnClientClick in the aspx file or as in my edited answer in PageLoad event to make it work. Putting it in the click handler will assign the onclick event only after the button is pressed and I didnt realised that before. Sorry for that. I checked it in my project and it works now. Additionally you may need to put the script tag inside server control so the client ids might be evaluated on the server.

Answer (score 0):

u can try this also

```
protected void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
    if (grdBudgetMgr.Rows.Count > 0)
    {

        if (confirmValue == "Yes")
        {


        }
    }
}    



<script type="text/javascript">
                    function Confirm() {
                        var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
                        confirm_value.type = "hidden";
                        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
                        if (confirm("Are you sure Want to submit all Budgeted Requirement ?")) {
                            confirm_value.value = "Yes";
                        } else {
                            confirm_value.value = "No";
                        }
                        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
                    }
                </script>
```